# How to store filter expressions as strings?

Tags: r, string, filter, parameters

For the analysis of a species database, I often need to change lots of criteria, depending on the projects scope etc.

As it is very inconvenient to always change the criteria within the main script itself, I started defining various parameters as variables in an *`exterior parameters.R`* file which will be copied to the project specific folders and adjusted there, and which will be sourced from the *`main.R`* file.

This work great, but now that I come to filter expressions, I can't find a way to store them as a string in my parameters file.

The standard filter expression will be this one:

```
 rlb == "1" | rlb == "2" | rlb== "3" | rlb == "G" | rlb == "R" | rld ==
 "1" | rld == "2" | rld== "3" | rld == "G" | rld == "R" | ffh2 > 1 | ffh4
 == 1 | ffh5 == 1 | spa1 == 1 | sap == 1
```

Due to the `""` in some of the parameters, I can't assign it as a string variable, cause R is complaining that there are unknown tokens or objects.

How can I assign this filter expression to a variable, so I can use it later e.g. with `eval(my_filter_variable)` etc to perform my filtering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `filter_`

You can pass your filter expression using `filter_` in `dplyr`:

```
mtcars %>%
    filter_("cyl == 4")
```

### Handling strings

Let's say that you want to take this further and handle strings, you could use *`''`* for your string in the filter:

```
data.frame(col_A = LETTERS[1:10],
           col_B = 1:10,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    filter_("col_A == 'A'")
```

#### Handling `"`

If you really want to pass your string as `"`, you have to escape quotes:

```
data.frame(col_A = LETTERS[1:10],
           col_B = 1:10,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
    filter_("col_A == \"A\"")
```

## Better approach

I would suggest that you avoid the approach above. Have a look at the suggestion below that let's you pass your column name using `sym` function. In `dplyr` pipeline you could make use of `rlang` that would give you more flexibility in building your filter expressions:

```
require(dplyr)
require(rlang)
col_nme <- sym("cyl")
flt_val <- 4
mtcars %>%
    filter(UQ(col_nme) == UQ(flt_val))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
mtcars %>%
    filter(UQ(col_nme) == flt_val)
```

As you don't have to unquote second argument.

### Side points

The syntax of your filter is:

```
rlb == "1" | rlb == "2" | rlb== "3" | rlb == "G" | rlb == "R" |
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
rlb %in% c("1", "2", "3" , "G" , "R")
```

the vector `c("1", "2", "3", "G", "R")` could be easily passed as a variable, without any addittional effort involving quosures or non-standard evaluation. I would start from simplifying filters then use simplified expressions via `rlang` features.

---

## Code sharing

Following the comment on code sharing, it may be good to look at the `sqldf` package:

```
require(sqldf)
sqldf(x = "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE CYL = 4")
```

This is would let you share your filters in SQL, which is usually more familiar then `dplyr` syntax.

Comment: filter_ did the trick in addition with changing the doublequotes to quotes (Of course I do not insist on using doublequotes, but that was my first try and filter() ate it. ) The "problem" with refining the filter statement is, that I plan to throw the parameters.R file at my coworkers to adjust it themselves, so everything which is not straightly comprehensible for them will lead to chaos. Of course I should have mentioned before that I already use dplyr with a lot of joy.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Konrad's methods, if the expression is a string, then we can use `parse_expr` from `rlang`

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    filter(!! parse_expr(expr1))
#   col_A col_B
#1     A     1
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame(col_A = LETTERS[1:10],
           col_B = 1:10,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

expr1 <-  "col_A == 'A' & col_B == 1"
```

Comment: Actually, my first mistake was that I didn't manage to make my expression a string because of the double quotes and did't get the idea to change sth with that. Saturday after a Fridays night! Well, thank you for your alternative solution, but I have to admit that yet another package is too much for me to handle ;) Thats why I prefer the "plain" dplyr approach over yours. Cheers!

Comment: Valid point, and it will also properly digest double quotes if needed: `expr1 <-  "col_A == \"A\" & col_B == 1"`.

Comment: @BerndV.  No problem.  But `rlang` is developed by the same team that developed tidyverse.  Note that some of the functions that work in the past are getting deprecated

Comment: @Konrad You are right that `filter_` does parse those  (same as `parse_expr`).  I heard that those `_` functions are deprecated

Comment: Ah, ok, nice to know. The whole tidyverse is already such an overwhelming approach for a semi-noob like me, and the possibilities seem to be unlimited. Constantly have to relearn again what I hardly acquired the last years. But now code of several hundred lines melts down to a few dozens sometimes. Its amazing!

Comment: @Konrad Just curious, are you getting different behaviour with the double quote expression you commented. For me, both of them are working fine

Comment: @akrun I've tried again, and this seems to [fail](https://gist.github.com/konradedgar/91ce41aec660a7cdeee1a4adb183dbae).

Comment: @Konrad  May be, it is a different package version?

Comment: @akrun `>> Vectorize(packageVersion)(pkg = c("dplyr", "rlang"))` :
`$dplyr: [1] 0 7 8` and `$rlang: [1] 0 3 1`. That's what I've.

Comment: @Konrad That is strange.  I do have the same version `packageVersion('rlang')
[1] ‘0.3.1’
> packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.7.8’`

Comment: @akrun Maybe R version? I've 3.5.2, I've tested this on [https://rdrr.io/snippets/](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) and it fails the same.

Comment: @Konrad  I also have 3.5.2 on a mac

Comment: @Konrad I noticed that you converted the string to  `sym`bol

Comment: @akrun So that will be the error source, interesting.

Comment: @Konrad It would be the issue, now it is no longer a string