# Generate R script adopting user input from shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dplyr, rlang

I would like to export the r code - which is evaluated at the time of activating an action button - together with the respective user input as r script.

My apologies, if I am being imprecise or this question has already been asked elsewhere, but I am not familiar with the proper terminology and keywords to search for.

I have the following UI ([similar to this app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html)) and added an actionbutton:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
                    column(4,
                           selectInput(
                                     "var",
                                     "Variables:",
                                     c("All", colnames(iris)),
                                     selected = c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length"),
                                     multiple = T)
                    ),
                    column(4,
                           textInput("filter",
                                     "Filter Data",
                                     value = "Sepal.Length < 5"))
          ),
          DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
          actionButton("script",
                       "Save script")
)
```

The idea is to have the user `select` columns from a dataset (`iris`) and `filter` it using standard r / dplyr syntax and quasiquotation ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494173/how-to-store-filter-expressions-as-strings))

```
server <- function(input, output){
          dat <- reactive({
                    data <- iris
                    if(!input$var %in% "All"){
                              data <- data %>% select(input$var)
                    }
                    if(input$filter != ""){
                              data <- data %>% filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(input$filter))
                    }
                    data
          })
          output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(dat()))
          # insert code below here
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works as intended. However, I would like to export the r code, that gives the desired output and save it in a new r-file. That is, upon pressing the action button the code is being printed (`cat`) and the user input (`input`) fills the blanks:

```
            observeEvent(input$script, {
                    cat('#this is an automatically generated r script
                         data <- iris
                         if(!',paste0("c(",paste(paste0('"',input$var, '"'), collapse = ","), ")"), '%in% "All"){
                                      data <- data %>% select(',paste(input$var, collapse = ","),')
                         }
                        if(',paste0("c(",paste(paste0('"',input$filter, '"'), collapse = ","), ")"),' != ""){
                             data <- data %>% filter(',input$filter,')
                         }', file =  "r_script.r")
          })
```

This abomination of code is actually working and the resulting `r_script.r` file contains the following code:

```
#this is an automatically generated r script
                         data <- iris
                         if(! c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length") %in% "All"){
                                      data <- data %>% select( Sepal.Length,Petal.Length )
                         }
                        if( c("Sepal.Length < 5")  != ""){
                             data <- data %>% filter( Sepal.Length < 5 )
                         }
```

**My question is:** Is there an easier way to access the underlying code being run on the server and export it as a r-script, preferable with the `if` statements already evaluated:

```
#this is an automatically generated r script
                         data <- iris                      
                         data <- data %>% select( Sepal.Length,Petal.Length )
                         data <- data %>% filter( Sepal.Length < 5 )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a package for this, it’s called shinymeta. I think it’s not on CRAN yet, so you have to use the [GitHub version](https://github.com/rstudio/shinymeta).

Comment: @TimTeaFan thank you for your comment and bringing this package to my attention. The demo alone looks really promising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `rlang` package to convert codes to an expression which can be either printed as text or evaluated. Example codes:

```r
server <- function(input,output,session){
    
    user_script <- reactiveVal()
    
    observe({
        req(input$var)
        req(input$filter)
        
        # you need to sanitize user input to prevent error, now I just wrote a tryCatch()
        dplyr_expr <- tryCatch({
            # check user input
            if(any(input$var == "All")){
                columns <- colnames(iris)
            } else {
                columns <- input$var
            }
            
            dplyr_expr <- expr({
                data <- iris                     
                data <- data %>% select( !!!syms(columns))
                data <- data %>% filter( !!parse_expr(input$filter) )    
            })
            # save script
            expression_string <- capture.output(dplyr_expr)
            script_text <- paste0(
                expression_string[2:(length(expression_string)-1)],collapse = "<br>"
            )
            
            user_script(script_text)
            # evaluate expression
            eval(dplyr_expr)
            user_script(script_text)
            output$table <- renderDataTable(data)
        },error = function(e){
            print("user input caused an error")
        })
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$script,{
        req(user_script())
        showModal(
            modalDialog(
                HTML(
                    paste(
                        "# this is an automatically generated r script<br>",
                        user_script()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    })
    
}
```

To help you understand better, let's do it outside shiny first.

#### Let's first simulate user input from UI:

```r
input1 <- c("Species","Sepal.Length")
input2 <- c("Sepal.Length < 5")
user_data <- iris
```

#### Server Processing

```r
# read user input and convert it to expression
dplyr_expr <- expr({
    data <- !!expr(user_data)                     
    data <- data %>% select( !!!syms(input1))
    data <- data %>% filter( !!!parse_expr(input2) )    
})
```

#### to return the value as a string:

```r
expression_string <- capture.output(dplyr_expr)
writeLines(paste0(expression_string[2:(length(expression_string)-1)],collapse = "\n"))
```

returns

```r
    data <- user_data
    data <- data %>% select(Species, Sepal.Length)
    data <- data %>% filter(Sepal.Length < 5)
```

#### To evaluate

```r
eval(dplyr_expr)
str(data)
```

returns

```r
'data.frame':   22 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sepal.Length: num  4.9 4.7 4.6 4.6 4.4 4.9 4.8 4.8 4.3 4.6 ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very elegantly done. One small question remains: Is it possible to incorporate the `if` construct in there? Leaving the input blank or set to `All` should preferably return all columns.

Comment: Just modified my question based on your comment. You can take the `if` construct outside of the expression.