# Create multiple columns based on the same condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to avoid repeating code when we want to mutate several new columns based on one condition?

For example, in the `mtcars` dataset, I want to create two new columns. One will categorize whether the car is "economic" or not, and another column will describe the color of a "label" each car gets.

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, am) %>%
  mutate(economic = case_when(mpg <= 17 & am == 0 ~ "no",
                              mpg > 17 & am == 1 ~ "yes"),
         
         label = case_when(mpg <= 17 & am == 0 ~ "red",
                           mpg > 17 & am == 1 ~ "green")) 

#>                      mpg am economic label
#> Mazda RX4           21.0  1      yes green
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  1      yes green
#> Datsun 710          22.8  1      yes green
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Valiant             18.1  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Duster 360          14.3  0       no   red
#> Merc 240D           24.4  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 230            22.8  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 280            19.2  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 280C           17.8  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 450SE          16.4  0       no   red
#> Merc 450SL          17.3  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2  0       no   red
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4  0       no   red
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4  0       no   red
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7  0       no   red
#> Fiat 128            32.4  1      yes green
#> Honda Civic         30.4  1      yes green
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9  1      yes green
#> Toyota Corona       21.5  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5  0       no   red
#> AMC Javelin         15.2  0       no   red
#> Camaro Z28          13.3  0       no   red
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3  1      yes green
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0  1      yes green
#> Lotus Europa        30.4  1      yes green
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8  1     <NA>  <NA>
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7  1      yes green
#> Maserati Bora       15.0  1     <NA>  <NA>
#> Volvo 142E          21.4  1      yes green
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In the code above, I had to specify the same condition twice, one for each new column.

- IF `mpg <= 17 & am == 0` THEN assign value X
- IF `mpg > 17 & am == 1` THEN assign value Y

Could I use this set of conditions to mutate several new columns, such that each column will have its own X and Y values?

---

In my real-life data, I often have complex conditions that give rise to mutating many new columns, and I find myself repeating the same code for conditions over and over again. Is there a way to outline the conditions once and then create multiple columns based on the same set of conditions?

---

EDIT 1

---

I wonder -- although it would **not** address the question above fully -- would there be a way to store conditionals into objects and unpack those later? Something like:

```r
cond_1 <- {mpg <= 17 & am == 0}
cond_2 <- {mpg > 17 & am == 1}

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, am) %>%
  mutate(economic = case_when(cond_1  ~ "no",
                              cond_2  ~ "yes"),

         label = case_when(cond_1  ~ "red",
                           cond_2  ~ "green"))
```

It would at least make code more concise...

---

EDIT 2

---

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54494521/6105259), I learned how to answer the question I posed in *EDIT 1*:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

cond_1 <- parse_expr("mpg <= 17 & am == 0")
cond_2 <- parse_expr("mpg > 17 & am == 1")

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, am) %>%
  mutate(economic = case_when(!!cond_1  ~ "no",
                              !!cond_2  ~ "yes"),
         
         label = case_when(!!cond_1  ~ "red",
                           !!cond_2  ~ "green"))

#>                      mpg am economic label
#> Mazda RX4           21.0  1      yes green
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  1      yes green
#> Datsun 710          22.8  1      yes green
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Valiant             18.1  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Duster 360          14.3  0       no   red
#> Merc 240D           24.4  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 230            22.8  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 280            19.2  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 280C           17.8  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 450SE          16.4  0       no   red
#> Merc 450SL          17.3  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2  0       no   red
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4  0       no   red
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4  0       no   red
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7  0       no   red
#> Fiat 128            32.4  1      yes green
#> Honda Civic         30.4  1      yes green
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9  1      yes green
#> Toyota Corona       21.5  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5  0       no   red
#> AMC Javelin         15.2  0       no   red
#> Camaro Z28          13.3  0       no   red
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2  0     <NA>  <NA>
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3  1      yes green
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0  1      yes green
#> Lotus Europa        30.4  1      yes green
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8  1     <NA>  <NA>
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7  1      yes green
#> Maserati Bora       15.0  1     <NA>  <NA>
#> Volvo 142E          21.4  1      yes green
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**However, this only makes the code easier to read. But the main problem of this post – repetition of conditionals – remains.**

Comment: So in this revised scenario, what is your problem exactly?

Comment: That I need to repeat the same conditions more than once. This is a toy example, but imagine a situation where there aren't only `economic` and `label` columns to create, but 10 new columns based on the same set of conditions. I don't want to repeat code 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an optimal solution but one way would be to use the previous columns created as an input to create new columns. This would avoid writing the conditions again and again.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, am) %>%
  mutate(economic = case_when(mpg <= 17 & am == 0 ~ "no",
                              mpg > 17 & am == 1 ~ "yes"),
         label = recode(economic, "no" = "red", "yes" = "green"))
```

Comment: Yes, it would work, but I think such code would be confusing.